# Proving that a matrix is diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $\alpha$ be a linear operator on V, suppose $\alpha$ is bijective and $\alpha^2$  is diagonalisable, and $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed with $\operatorname{char}(\mathbb{F})\neq 2$. Prove that $\alpha$ is diagonalisable.

Some how characteristic field must be used but I am not sure where hence I suspect my approach is wrong:

Let the eigenspace for eigenavalue $\lambda$ of $\alpha$ be $E^{\alpha}_{\lambda}$. Then for each eigenvalue $ \lambda_i$ of $\alpha$ we have 
$$ E^{\alpha}_{\lambda_i} \subseteq  E^{\alpha^2}_{\lambda_i^2}$$

And I need to show the converse, that if v is an eigenvectors of $\alpha^2$ then it is an eigenvector of $\alpha$. I can't prove this direction but once done then the conclusion should be straightforward, and I have no idea how to use the fact that $\alpha$ does not have 0 as an eigenvalue

Comment: NB that we cannot (fully) drop the condition that $\alpha$ is bijective, since $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}^2 = 0$ is diagonalizable but $\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ is not.

Comment: Nor can we drop the characteristic requirement, as, in characteristic $2$, the matrix $\alpha=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable, but $\alpha^2$ is the identity.

Comment: It is not true in general that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $\alpha^2$, then it must be an eigenvector of $\alpha$. Consider The linear transfromation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $\alpha(x,y) = (x,-y)$. Then $\alpha^2$ is the identity, so **every** nonzero vector is an eigenvector of $\alpha^2$; but $(1,1)$ is **not** an eigenvector of $\alpha$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is **not** diagonalizable and invertible then there exists a vector $v$ and a non-zero scalar $\lambda$ such that $(\alpha - \lambda)^2 v = 0$ but $(\alpha - \lambda) v \ne 0$. That is, $v$ is a generalized eigenvector but not an eigenvector. Now try to show that the same $v$ is a generalized eigenvector (but not an eigenvector) for $\alpha^2$ (with eigenvalue $\lambda^2$), proving that $\alpha^2$ is not diagonalizable. You will have to use at some point that $2 \lambda \ne 0$, which is where
the characteristic assumption comes in.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\alpha^2$ is diagonalizable, its minimal polynomial splits (well, yes, because $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed) *and* it has no repeated roots. That is, it is of the form
$$m(t) = (t-\lambda_1)\cdots (t-\lambda_k)$$
with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ pairwise distinct.

Now, that means that $\alpha$ satisfies the polynomial
$$(t^2-\lambda_1)\cdots(t^2-\lambda_k)$$
and thus, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ must divide this polynomial.

Can you take it from here, and do you see why you need all three hypothesis, that $\alpha$ is invertible, that $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed, *and* that its characteristic is not $2$?